# Why was my flag to delete my question declined?

Tags: support

I tried to delete a question but I got a message saying that I can't because it has answers, and asked me to flag this for a moderator attention so this is what I did but then I got a message saying:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What did I do wrong? Doesn't this problem need moderator intervention?

See here is my question: [Why do current and electrons flow in opposite directions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68911/why-do-current-and-electrons-flow-in-opposite-directions)

which has 10700 views while the other one which my question is closed as duplicate of only has 3000 views.

My question is distracting from the other one for that I want to delete it. Also I have three badges I've earned can you please undo them because they are illegal.

I'm sorry for asking the duplicate question but I didn't know it was a duplicate.

Comment: The problem doesn't need moderator intervention because we don't delete questions with upvoted answers.

Comment: But it is distracting from the other question, that's why I want to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I merged the two for you. Requesting a merge makes sense here, if you request deletion the moderator will look at the post from that POV and decline it.

Always, try to be specific in flags, it really helps especially when there are a lot of flags to go through :)

Comment: But what about the badges?

Comment: Don't worry about the badges. Accept them as well-earned recognition that you asked exactly the question that a lot of people have in their heads, and for providing the site with a valuable signpost to a good question and answers.